# Vector space of approximation (Finite element method)

Tags: functional-analysis, finite-element-method

I am following the book Topics in Functional analysis and applications by S. Kesavan. The text introduces the finite element method as:

> Let $V$ be a real Hilbert space and let $a: V × V → \mathbb{R}$ be a $V$-elliptic and continuous bilinear form. Let $f \in V$. Then by the Lax-Milgram theorem there exists a unique $u \in V$ such that$$
> a(u, v) = (f, v). \quad \forall v \in V \tag{3.7.1}
> $$
>   We have seen in Section 3.2 several examples of this set-up. We now turn to the approximation of the solution $u$. The Galerkin method described in Section 3.4 gives us an idea as to how to proceed to do this.
>
> Let $h > 0$ be a parameter. To it we associate $V_h$ which is a *finite dimensional subspace* of $V$. Now consider the following problem: Find $u_h \in V_h$ such that$$
> a(u_h, v_h) = (f, v_h). \quad \forall v_h \in V_h \tag{3.7.2}
> $$
>   Since $a$ is continuous and $V$-elliptic, it is so on $V_h$ as well and by the Lax-Milgram theorem, $u_h$ exists uniquely.
>
> In Section 3.2, we have seen several examples of the program set out in Step 1 above. Thus we will have a bounded domain $\mit Ω$ and a problem set out in a space $V$ which will usually be a subspace of $H^1({\mit Ω})$ (if the problem is of the second order) or $H^2({\mit Ω})$ (for the fourth order problems).
>
> The basic idea to construct the spaces $V_h$ is to partition the domain into smaller entities, say, triangles. Assume, for simplicity, that $\mit Ω$  is a polygonal domain. A triangulation $\mathscr{T}_h$ of $\mit Ω$ is a partition of $\mit Ω$ into triangles (i.e. “$n$”-simplices in $\mathbb{R}^n$) such that each “side” is either part of the boundary $\mit Γ$ or is a “side” of an adjacent triangle. Thus we do not allow triangles as shown in Fig. 13.
>
> Thus we have a triangulation as follows

[image]

> We denote by $K$ any generic triangle in $\mathscr{T}_h$, The “$h$” now stands for$$
> h = \max_{K \in \mathscr{T}_h} \operatorname{diam}(K)
> $$
>   so that as $h → 0$ the triangles are smaller and smaller and we get a fine mesh on $\mit Ω$.
>
> Now we say that $V_h$ must be a space of piecewise polynomials with respect to $\mathscr{T}_h$. That is we fix an integer $k$ and if $P_k$ stands for polynomials of degree $\leqslant k$ in $n$ variables, then we wish that if $v \in V_h$ then $v|_K \in P_k$ for every $K \in \mathscr{T}_h$. Thus $V_h$ is clearly finite dimensional and once $k$ is fixed, the dimension of $V_h$ can be increased by just refining the given triangulation. Thus as $h → 0$, $N(h) → ∞$.

1. Can someone explain me the last paragraph of the last page where the text mentions about the subspace $V_h$ as the space of polynomials?

   What is $\left.v\right|_K$?

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega$ is the domain of the PDE we're trying to solve. When they say to partition $\Omega$ into a mesh of triangles, they really mean to discretize $\Omega$ as the vertices of said triangles (call them "nodes"). They want to find an approximate solution $u_h \in V_h \subset V$ that is at least defined at every node in our discretization of $\Omega$. For points in $\Omega$ that are between nodes, $u_h$ is interpolated as a polynomial of order $k$. Thus $V_h$ (which contains $u_h$) is a space of piecewise polynomials "with respect" to the triangles $\mathscr{T}_h$. That is, each $v \in V_h$ is an entire piecewise-polynomial function defined everywhere on $\Omega$ and they use the symbol $v|_K \in P_k$ to denote the "piece" of it that is "over" (interpolates through) a specific triangle $K \in \mathscr{T}_h$. To clarify, if our mesh contains $N$ triangles then for all $\omega \in \Omega$ we have,
$$
v(\omega) =
\begin{cases}
v|_{K_1}(\omega) \in P_k & \text{for } \omega \in K_1 \subset \Omega\\
\vdots \\
v|_{K_N}(\omega) \in P_k & \text{for } \omega \in K_N \subset \Omega
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: 1. $v \in V_h$ is defined on $\Omega$?

2.If $1$ is true, then as $\left.v\right|_K \in P_k$ and $\Omega=\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} K_i$, deg$(v)\le k$. Are we sure about that?

3. What is the relation between $V, \Omega$ and $ V_h,\Omega$?

Comment: $V$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space of functions defined on $\Omega$, and $V_h$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$. I agree that the mesh should be chosen such that the union of all the triangles yields the entire domain. I don't see how these ideas are conflicting.

Comment: I never said we have a contradiction. The text didn't mention specifically that $V$ is a real Hilbert space of "functions". Now, since $V_h$ is finite dimensional space of functions, are we sure all of these are polynomials or can be approximated by polynomials?

Comment: For $(3.7.1)$ and $(3.7.2)$ to hold, $V$ only needs to be a Hilbert space. However, after those statements are made, the text proceeds to explain the finite element method for solving problems of the form $(3.7.2)$ where specifically $V$ is a subspace of $H^p(\Omega)$ [which is an infinite-dimensional space of functions on $\Omega$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Functions_vanishing_at_the_boundary). When we say that $V_h$ is a "finite-dimensional" subspace of $V$, we mean that it can be defined by a finite set of parameters (like $P^k$ can).

Comment: The choice to let $V_h$ be piecewise polynomials (with respect to a some polygonal domain mesh) is not required for the finite element method, but is traditional and effective, since they are linear in their parameters and easy to integrate.

Comment: Also, it might clear things up to explain that when they say $P_k$ is the set of polynomials of degree $\leq k$, they mean that anything from $\ (\omega +3)\ $ to $\ (\omega^k - \omega^2 + \omega + 3)\ $  are valid members of $P_{k > 2}$. I.e. leading coefficients are allowed to be zero.

Comment: Thanks for the traditional and effective part. That basically cleared everything. For the last line, once we fix $k$, each $v \in V_h$ has the property : deg$(v \le k)$. So, how does refining the triangulation now increases the dimension of $V_h$ since  deg$(v \le k) \, \implies \, \{1,x,\ldots,x^{k}\}$ generates $V_h$?

Comment: Say we have gone with tradition and let $V_h$ be the set of *piecewise* polynomials (order $\leq k$) w.r.t. our mesh on $\Omega$. Suppose our mesh has $N$ regions (triangles). Then $V_h$ is $kN$-dimensional because we will need $kN$ parameters to fully define all $N$ different $v|_K \in P_k$'s that make up a single $v \in V_h$. There are two ways to increase the dimensionality of $V_h$. We can increase $k$ or increase $N$. Traditionally, we fix $k$ (called "choosing an element type" since the $v|_K$ are called "elements") and instead we decrease $h$ to increase $N$ ("mesh refinement").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78761/discussion-between-yasir-and-jnez71).